# Why would a GFI blink red

Tags: gfci, dryer, washer

A detached garage on a property was recently wired with a 220 circuit to accommodate lighting, washer, and electric dryer .

The problem is the GFI for the washer blinks red.

Answer (score 13):

Effective June 29, 2015, all GFCI receptacles and circuit breakers must have an auto-monitoring (self-test) feature that automatically conducts a periodic internal test to confirm that the GFCI is able respond to a ground fault. If a problem is detected, the GFCI must trip and deny power or provide a visual and/or audible indication.

**Green Status**

Dual indicator:

- On initial installation - If no power to load, device has been wired incorrectly
- Normal operation - GFCI has passed self-test and is providing power

**Red Status**

- Blinking = Initial self-test upon first power up
- Solid or blinking = Press TEST and RESET buttons to reset GFCI
- If GFCI will not reset OR solid or blinking red continues, replace device

**No Power**

- GFCI in tripped state, no power
- Press RESET button
- If GFCI will not reset, no power on the circuit

**Self-Test Indications:** 
If the Status Indicator Light is solid or flashing RED a problem may exist. Press the TEST button to trip the GFCI. If unable to Reset, replace the GFCI.

**NOTE: The status indicator may flash Red at power "ON" and Reset.**

[image]

Comment: How fast do I need to replace it? It's blinking red and it started happening after i finished fixing a faucet?