# what causes the red light to continue blinking even resetting my gfci outlet

Tags: bathroom

what causes the red light to blink, after resetting the GFCI outlet?  is it faulty, I can't seem to get it to stay green.  help

Comment: What make and model is your GFCI?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This will be closed soon as a duplicate; you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

[Why would a GFI blink red](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/99052/why-would-a-gfi-blink-red)

**Red Status**

- Blinking = Initial self-test upon first power up
- Solid or blinking = Press TEST **and** RESET buttons to reset GFCI
- If GFCI will not reset OR solid or blinking red continues, replace device

Comment: This looks like the right answer, but for the good of the site, its better to mark this one as a duplicate rather than adding another answer here.